# How to install Filemaker on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, install, filemaker

I am not familiar with the iPad but my MacBook died and I can't afford a new one. How can I install software that is not from the Apple Store on my iPad? I have the software `.ipa` file, but how do I install it?

Answer (score 3):

You can’t install software that’s not from the App Store except by compiling it yourself from source code (but you need a Mac to do that). And iPads can’t just run Mac software even if Apple would let you install it. They have different CPUs and a different operating system, and can only run software designed to run on iOS. There’s no iOS version of FileMaker (though there’s a client app available).

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself an Apple ID, if you dont already have one, and get FileMaker Go from the app store. It’s free and allows you to run all your FileMaker databases on your iPad. Use iTunes to transfer the databases or send them to an email account on your iPad.

You won’t be able to make any changes to the schema or layout, but you can work with the data. For that you would need FileMaker Pro on a Mac or Windows machine.